# create data container from another docker image

Tags: linux, docker, containers, busybox

I have a docker image that is about **900MB** it has a directory `/data` where all the data i want are in and also a `/data/.git` directory that i will like to exclude.

I will like to create a data container(using busybox image for example) with only the data under the `/data` excluding the `/data/.git` directory

How do i do this in the most efficient way?

The `/data` excluding the `/data/.git` is only about **130MB**

So basically i will have data container having roughly 130MB to 200MB compared to the other docker image that is 900MB huge

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd migrate to a named volume, and create it with the following:

```
docker run -it --rm -v data-vol:/target your_image \
  /bin/bash -c "cp -av /data/* /target"
```

The `cp -av /data/* /target` will ignore all of the dot files, so you may need to add others manually if you have more than just the ".git", e.g. `cp -av /data/* /data/.app-files /target`

If you're willing to first create it with a full copy of /data and then delete the .git folder later, that's even easier:

```
docker run -it --rm -v data-vol:/data your_image rm -rf /data/.git
```

As long as "data-vol" has not been initialized, it will be created with the full /data contents by Docker. And then the first command you run is to clean the ".git" folder.

Once you have the "data-vol" volume, you can reused it in another other container with:

```
docker run -v data-vol:/data another_image
```

Comment: here is what i got

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/data:/data my-first-image /bin/bash -c "cp -av /data/* /data"
cp: cannot stat '/data/*': No such file or directory
```

and the first image does have all files under `/data`

Comment: actually it works now after using a different name instead using data for both source and destination, choose a different name and that was it...now the question is how to i start a data container with the files i copied over using something like busybox image for example?

Comment: There's no need for a data container, those are effectively depreciated, just run any image with your named volume mount to any location.

Comment: ok i have a question here, what is the difference between data volumes and volume mounts on host?

Comment: Named volumes are a replacement for data containers, they let you manage data separate from containers (`docker volume ...`). Volume mounts to the host are a direct map to the host filesystem.

Comment: ok i got confused there then, so what does `data-col` stands for here `-v data-vol:/target`? i was thinking it is a directory on the host. Am i correct or wrong?

Comment: `data-vol` is the name of the named volume. After running, it will be visible with `docker volume ls`. Host volumes need a full path (`/path/to/host/vol`).

Comment: ok here is the only thing though..how does data volumes play out in CI (continuous integration) where the runner builds the images and everything so how will that data-volume be viewable to the running containers?